# Как убрать задублированный шаблон в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

Заметил, что некоторые шаблоны, такие как например шаблон нового класса в окне add new item отображается дважды, при выборе что одного, что другого создаются абсолютно одинаковые заготовки класса, как это поправить т.е. убрать задублированный шаблон?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта проблема может быть вызвана установкой Xamarin-а. Имена его шаблонов прописано ссылкой на стандартные ресурсы:

```
Name Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2245"
```

Поэтому они выглядят как дубликаты в диалоге добавления.

Можно руками исправить все *.vstemplate-файлы, прописав в них имена вида "Xamarin C# class" вместо "Package=".

Шаблоны Xamarin лежат в

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\3.11.785.0\T\IT\Code\GeneralClass.zip
```

Студия кэширует шаблоны, так что после исправления нужно

- запустить `cmd` с правами администратора
- перейти в `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`
- запустить `devenv /installvstemplates`

<sub>решение взято принятого ответа на вопрос топикастера на enSO: [How to remove duplicate class template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737597/1988244)</sub>